# firefox addon : adding icon to context menu

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm trying to build a firefox addon & I want to add image/icon in the right click content menu  , for example, firebug had an icon in the right click context menu,

[image]

I wanna do something similar, my addon also consists of menu items

**structure of my addon in context menu** :

```
[icon] [menu] 
            [menu item 1]
            [menu item 2]
            [menu item 3]
            [menu item 4]
```

How can I do  it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set the [`image` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/menu), give the element the [class `menu-iconic`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/menu#Related) and store the image so that you can access it.

XUL:

```
<menu id="someid" label='your label'
          class="menu-iconic"
          image='chrome://addon/skin/image.png'>
...
</menu>
```

JavaScript:

You can also set or change the image dynamically (get a reference to the element first):

```
menu.setAttribute('image', 'chrome://addon/skin/image.png');
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked :), struggling to this for the past 2 hours, finally `class = "menu-iconic"` made my job get done. but one question, how does it got iconic on adding a `class` attribute ?

Comment: Well I guess that Firefox uses some CSS to show the image and maybe also align the text correctly. In the end, the XUL interface is also just styled with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a context menu using the new Mozilla Add-ons SDK image using the image property

under **Optional options**:

just add the image attribute like this

```
 var menuItem = contextMenu.Menu({
    include: "*.stackoverflow.com",
    label: "do something",
    image: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA ...",
    context: contextMenu.SelectorContext('div.someclass'),
    contentScriptFile: data.url("cs.js"),
    items: [
        contextMenu.Item({ label: "Item 1", data: "item1" }),
        contextMenu.Item({ label: "Item 2", data: "item2" }),
        contextMenu.Item({ label: "Item 3", data: "item3" })
      ]
});
```

image: The item's icon, a string URL. The URL can be remote, a reference to an image in the add-on's data directory, or a data URI.

[Mozilla context menu help page for Addon SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu)

Comment: This question explicitly has the XUL tag and does not have the firefox-addon-sdk tag. While it is not *wrong* to provide an answer here that is for the Add-On SDK, the wording of your first paragraph implies that there is something wrong with using XUL at this time. That is not the case. It has not, yet, been deprecated.

Comment: The only statement that has been made is that deprecation may happen sometime in the future. "[We don’t have a specific timeline for deprecation, but most likely it will take place within 12 to 18 months from now.](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/08/21/the-future-of-developing-firefox-add-ons/)" Now being 2015-08-21 in that statement.

Comment: I wouldn't to spend time developing something that is not really documented anymore and will be depreciated in ~1 years time, but each to their own